# How to inject Dagger dependendcies anywhere, except Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I'm new to Dagger, so couple of things are still hard to grasp for me.

I have a component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        AppModule::class,
        AuthModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        @BindsInstance
        fun appModule(@Named("application") app:Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(application: CommonApplication)
}
```

and a module:

```
@Module
class AppModule {
    @Inject
    @Named("application")
    internal lateinit var application: Application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplicationContext() = application.applicationContext

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication() = application
}
```

In Activity where I want to inject dependencies I use

```
AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this/*activity*/)
```

And here is a question:

Just for understanding. If I want to inject `applicationContext`, that provides by AppModule into  child class. For example I have a class MainActivity with child class. And I want to Inject applicationContext only to this child, **instead of passing it as parameter.** How to do this?

```
class MainActivity {

    ChildClazz child;    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this/*activity*/)
    }

}

class ChildClazz {
    /* HOW TO INJECT DEPENDENCY HERE?*/
    @Inject
    context:Context
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is constructor injection

```
class ChildClazz
@Inject
constructor(private val context: Context) {

}
```

and then, in your activity you can inject it. If dagger is able to resolve all the dependencies of your `ChildClazz` you are good to go

```
@Inject
lateinit var child: ChildClazz;
```

in your `AppModule` you could have somethng like

```
@Provides
fun provideContext(app: Application): Context = app.applicationContext
```

this will provide you with the application context

`AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this/*activity*/)` has to be called before the `super.onCreate`

Comment: How Dagger knows (in this case) about where it should inject Context?

Comment: you need a `@Provide` method for that

Comment: sir, can you post more detailed answer? With full description of classes? Sorry, my head is burning of this Dagger((

Comment: I did edit my answer. You just need to add the method to AppModule and move inject before oncreate. The rest should work